# Run-time Error '1004' in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason I keep getting a range global runtime error when I try to run the following script.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub crossUpdate()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheet1.Cells.Range("A2").End(xlDown)

Range(rng).Select



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code into:

```
Sub crossUpdate()
   Dim rng As Range
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown)
   rng.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you **select** a range, you must have already **Select** ed the proper sheet. Also fix the **Select** command Try:

```
Sub crossUpdate()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Cells.Range("A2").End(xlDown)
    Sheet1.Select
    rng.Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

This version will **Select** the block of cells:

```
Sub crossUpdate()
    Dim rng As Range, N As Long
    Sheet1.Select
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
    rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, that worked, but it didn't do what I thought it would do.  How would I modify it so that it selected from cell A2 to the last populated cell.  (So far its only selecting the last populated cell)